# Java files became encoded

Tags: java, eclipse, encode

So I'm not sure what the reason is/was, but now (only)two out of my five .java source file are loading in Eclipse as a single row of squares. I opened it in notepad and it showed the encoding (a lot of East Asian characters and I even saw a sun and stuff), but now it only shows squares in Eclipse, and nothing elsewhere.

Can somebody explain what may have happened and offer a solution?

Comment: When you're over your loss, I recommend you look into version control systems such as `git`.

Comment: Maybe you try to open the `*.class` files instead of the `*.java` ones.

Comment: They're in the src folder and the other three open correctly. @SubOptimal

Comment: @PhilC Then you best should post the hex dump of the first let say 20 bytes. Probably the files have some magic bytes to identify their type.

Comment: the abcdef is all dots000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 - that doesn't seem too okay to me. only zeroes

Comment: So you think I deserve abuse because you've messed up your files. Well I hope the Indians come back to reclaim their land while you're carving the turkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the file in Eclipse and select 'Replace With > Local History' Eclipse will show you a list of previous versions of the file (if it has any). You can replace the bad current version from those.

Take the time to set up a backup system. Also use a version control system like Git or SVN to keep good copies of your files.

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences -> Workspace ->  Text file encoding and other UTF-8

Comment: It was set to default (cp1252) and so I tried to set it to utf 8, but nothing happened.